# Read xlsx convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, excel

Is it possible to read the following xlsx file with PHP and then convert it to a array like this?

I think I need a Excel class that supports coordinates.

[image: img]

```
array("Date" => "05-jan", "Room" => "205", "Activity" => "");
array("Date" => "05-jan", "Room" => "209", "Activity" => "Test1");

array("Date" => "06-jan", "Room" => "205", "Activity" => "");
array("Date" => "06-jan", "Room" => "205", "Activity" => "Test2");

array("Date" => "07-jan", "Room" => "205", "Activity" => "");
array("Date" => "07-jan", "Room" => "209-pc", "Activity" => "Test3");

array("Date" => "08-jan", "Room" => "205", "Activity" => "");
array("Date" => "08-jan", "Room" => "209-pc", "Activity" => "");

array("Date" => "09-jan", "Room" => "205", "Activity" => "");
array("Date" => "09-jan", "Room" => "209-pc", "Activity" => "");
```

With this code I get the content.

https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

```
require('php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require('SpreadsheetReader.php');
$Reader = new SpreadsheetReader('2015.xlsx');
 $Sheets = $Reader -> Sheets();


foreach ($Sheets as $Index => $Name)
{

    $Reader -> ChangeSheet($Index);

    foreach ($Reader as $Row)
    {
        print_r($Row);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => 2 - 2015 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => 5-Jan [3] => 6-Jan [4] => 7-Jan [5] => 8-Jan[6] => 9-Jan ) 
  Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Monday [3] => Tuesday [4] => Wednesday [5] => Thursday [6] => Friday ) 
   Array ( [0] => 205 [1] => Fo. [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) 
  Array ( [0] => 24+ [1] => Ef. [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => ) 
   Array ( [0] => 209-pc [1] => Fo. [2] => Test1 [3] => Test2 [4] => Test3 [5] => [6] => ) 
Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => Ef. [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => )
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at any of the existing PHP libraries for reading Excel files, like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)?

Comment: You can try something like that: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p6.html

Comment: I can get all the data from the Excel file. But i dont have every cell in a variable.

Comment: So show the code you've got so far, and the array that it is giving you

Comment: `and the array that it is giving you`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Excel Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)

This will store your excel data as an array, as you need. Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

There was a probleme with my current SpreadsheetReader version also.

You can fix by changing your Sheets() method in your SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php file

```
      public function Sheets() {

      if ($this -> Sheets === false) {
          $this -> Sheets = array();
          foreach ($this -> WorkbookXML -> sheets -> sheet as $Index => $Sheet) {
              $AttributesWithPrefix = $Sheet -> attributes('r', true);
              $Attributes = $Sheet -> attributes();
              $rId = 0;
              $sheetId = 0;
              foreach ($AttributesWithPrefix as $Name => $Value) {
                  if ($Name == 'id') {
                     $rId = (int)str_replace('rId', '', (string)$Value);
                     break;
                  }
              }

              foreach ($Attributes as $Name => $Value) {
                  if ($Name == 'sheetId') {
                      $sheetId = (int)$Value;
                      break;
                  }
              }
              $this -> Sheets[min($rId, $sheetId)] = (string)$Sheet['name'];
          }
          ksort($this -> Sheets);
      } 
      return array_values($this -> Sheets);
  }
```